# Cannot take files from web into python using configpaser, io and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

This is my code:

```py
from uu import decode
import requests
import configparser
import io

global config

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SCOS-Apps/SCOS-App-Store/main/store-list.ini"

r = requests.get(url)

content = r.content.decode()
buf = io.StringIO(content)

config.read(content)

print("SCOS Store v1.0")
print("Commands:\n1. Install\n2. Remove\n3. Exit")
while True:
    command = input("> ")
    print(command)
    if (command == "1"):
        req = input("> Install > App: ")
        for x in (config["Apps"]["app-list"]):
            if config["Apps"]["name-" + x] == req:
                print("YES")
    if (command == "3"):
        exit()
```

When I try to run it everything goes okay until the "Install" option is selected (I have made a test package named "Test"), then it doesn't want to to work, as it raises a key error.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution, what it's supposed to do is output "YES" when a package is detected successfully, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Did you read the KeyError?

Comment: What is `buf` used for?

Comment: Please check and debug your code with things like printing `config.sections()`.

Comment: The [configparser documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) is also useful to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigParser.read()` requires a filename; not a file object. Now it just does nothing (it will silenty skip non-existing files), and you end up with an empty ConfigParser instance.

You want `ConfigParser.read_file(buf)`.

But easier is to use `ConfigParser.read_string(content)`:

```
mport requests
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SCOS-Apps/SCOS-App-Store/main/store-list.ini"

r = requests.get(url)

content = r.content.decode()

config.read_string(content)
```